# Modularizing Spring security core and rest in a Private plugin so that it can be reused

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security, grails-plugin

We make a lot of use of spring security core and rest plugins in many apps. So instead of configuring it in each and every app, we decided to create a private plugin to do this functionality by following [Burt's blog to convert grails application to plugins](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973).

Specified spring security core and rest in BuidConfig.groovy of private plugin.
We created MyCoreConfig.groovy file and included all spring security core and rest configuration in it, so we can merge this config with Main application config.

The problem is configuration files like BuildConfig.groovy,Config.groovy and resources.groovy(we have customUserDetailsService bean) are excluded while packaging plugin. So we are merging config and resource file in following way

```
def doWithSpring = {
    // TODO Implement runtime spring config (optional)
    mergeConfig(application)

    userDetailsService(com.organisation.app.CustomUserDetailsService){
            grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    }

}

def onConfigChange = { event ->
    // TODO Implement code that is executed when the project configuration changes.
    // The event is the same as for 'onChange'.
    this.mergeConfig(application)
}

private void mergeConfig(GrailsApplication app) {
    ConfigObject currentConfig = app.config.grails.myCoreConfig
    ConfigSlurper slurper = new ConfigSlurper(Environment.getCurrent().getName());
    ConfigObject secondaryConfig = slurper.parse(app.classLoader.loadClass("MyCoreConfig"))
    ConfigObject config = new ConfigObject();
    config.putAll(secondaryConfig.myCoreConfig.merge(currentConfig))
    app.config.grails.myCoreConfig= config;
}
```

Plugin works fine when all config and resource files are in their respective places.

When we test plugin by commenting configuration from Config.groovy so as to take it from newly created MyCoreConfig.groovy and deleting resources.groovy so as it can take from doWithSpring closure, spring security's core and rest functionality doesn't work.

We even packaged the plugin as jar and included in our main application, and as expected it didn't work either.

So is this approach to extract common functionality in a private plugin which depends on public plugins correct?

Where are we going wrong?

Do people separately configure spring security core or rest in every app or do they follow different methodology to achieve this?

Any pointers in the right direction would be of great help.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: i never used it in such a way, so just a shot in the dark: does your service there work if you remove the wrapping "beans = "?  `userDetails...() {}` should be enough.  also what is "does not work" exactly?

Comment: @cfrick If wrapping bean is in resources.groovy and all configuration is in plugin's Config.groovy it works smoothly. We want this whole configuration stuff to be taken from MyCoreConfig.groovy which will be merged with main applications Config.groovy. Also as resources.groovy is excluded while packaging plugin, we need to put bean defination in doWithSpring closure. Whole spring security functionality "does not work" as it is not taking our configuration.

Comment: that is what mean: in the `doWithSpring{}` block, writing just `userDetail...` would be enough (no wrapping `beans = {...}` is needed) in your `*GrailsPlugin.groovy`.  if in doubt check https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy

Comment: @cfrick I tried that with and without `beans = { }` wrapping but no success.